# Ruby and some brain teaser

Tags: ruby

At the office, we had this little brain teaser:

```
class Bicycle
    def spares
        {tire_size: 21}.merge(local_spares)
    end

    def local_spares
        {}
    end
end

class RoadBike < Bicycle
    def local_spares
       {tape_color: 'red'}
    end
end

roadbike = RoadBike.new

roadbike.spares
```

Most of us didn't get what `roadbike.spares` output is unless we ran the whole code in the console. We had our different hunch on the behaviour but can anyone break it down to me what really happened here?

If anyone's wondering, the output is `{tire_size: 21, tape_color: 'red'}`

Comment: I'm disappointed by the down votes. Coming from a non-technical background that worked myself up in ruby, it's hard for me to research terms such as *method overriding*, I was completely stomped what keyword to search for in google, thanks for the answers though, I got it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called *method overriding*. The `RoadBike#local_spares` method overrides the `Bicycle#local_spares` method because `RoadBike` *inherits* from `Bicycle`.

When you send a message to an object, Ruby will try to find a method with the same name as the message to execute. It first looks at the object's class, then at that class's superclass, then at *that* class's superclass and so on.

When you send a `RoadBike` object the `spares` message, it will first try (and fail) to find a method named `spares` in `RoadBike`. Then it will look into its superclass (`Bicycle`) and succeed.

The body of *that* method contains a message send of `local_spares` to the receiver object. Again, Ruby tries to find a method named `local_spares` in the class of the object (still `RoadBike`) and succeeds, so it executes that method.

This is all just standard inheritance and method overriding. There's nothing really special or surprising or "brain teaserish" about that. In fact, this is pretty much the *whole point* of inheritance and method overriding: that more specialized objects can provide more specialized implementations than their more general parents.

---

Note: the method lookup algorithm is in reality a bit more involved than that.

First off, what happens if there is no more superclass, and the method still hasn't been found? In that case, Ruby will send the message `method_missing` to the receiver and pass along the name of the method that it tried to look up. Only if the `method_missing` method also can't be found, will Ruby `raise` a `NoMethodError`.

And secondly, there are singleton classes, included modules, prepended modules, and Refinements to consider. So, really Ruby will look at the object's singleton class first, before it looks at the class and then the superclass and so on. And "look at the class" actually means look first at the prepended modules (in reverse order), then at the class itself, and then at the included modules (again in reverse order). Oh, and that has to be done recursively as well, so for each prepended module look first at the prepended modules of that module, then at the module itself, then the included modules and so forth.

(Oh, and Refinements throw a another wrinkle in this, obviously.)

Most of the Ruby implementations simplify this algorithm greatly by separating their internal notion of what a "class" is from the programmer's notion, by introducing the concept of "hidden classes" (YARV calls them "virtual classes") that exist inside the implementation but aren't exposed to the programmer. So, for example, the singleton class of an object would be a hidden class, and the class pointer of the object would simply point to the singleton class and the superclass pointer of the singleton class would point to the *actual* class of the object. When you include a module into a class, the implementation will synthesize a hidden class (which YARV calls an "include class") for the module and insert it as the superclass of the class and make the former superclass the superclass of the hidden class. Methods like `Object#class` and `Class#superclass` would then simply follow the superclass chain until it finds the first non-hidden class and return that, instead of returning the class/superclass pointer directly.

This makes methods like `Object#class`, `Class#superclass` and `Module#ancestors` slightly more complex, because they have to skip hidden classes, but it simplifies the method lookup algorithm, which is one of the most important performance bottlenecks in any object-oriented system.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite obvious, `RoadBike#spares` (which is the same as `Bicycle#spares`, because `RoadBike` doesn't override this method) calls internally `RoadBike#local_spares`, merges its returned value to `{tire_size: 21}` hash and returns the result.
No surprise at all.

Comment: I guess you meant `RoadBike#local_spares`.

Comment: @toro2k of course I did, thank you, I make many stupid mistakes since today morning.